# Using a Script or regex to Add "printf" to every functions

Tags: python, c, regex, trace

In regex or Script (e.g. one written in python) how can I add

```
printf("TRACING: %s is called\n", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
```

at entry of all the function definitions, e.g.,

```
INT4
FunctionNameCouldBeAny (UINT4 ui)
{
    // insert here, at entry
    printf("TRACING: %s is called\n", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__); 
}
```

> 1. for one file `xxx.c`?
> 2. for all c files `*.c` under directory `/work_space/test/src`?

Please note, functions defined in the same file may share the same prefix, but not always.

COMMENT 1: `-finstrument-functions` does not work for my gcc; or else I have to provide `__cyg_profile_func_enter()/exit()` functions, and find a way to print out the name from binary address. I wonder if there is more efficient way from regex.

Comment: [Is this for](http://catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html#goal) debugging purposes? If so, you'd be better served to use an interactive debugger.

Comment: It is probably better to find a way to "instrument" your function calls rather than edit the source code itself.  Using instrumentation allows you to get the trace you want.

Comment: Lookup function instrumenting in the gcc manual.

Comment: Why not use the logging module? You have four levels: debug information,info,warnings and critical errors, so you can set your program's verbosity easily. And something you may be interested in: the log strings can be formatted to include the **name of the current function**.

Comment: hi, outis, unfortunately, i have to use a given debugger for a huge legacy code, and -finstrument-functions does not work for the debugger. or else i need to provide the cyg functions,then find some way to print function names out from the binary address. This is a bit complicated. I wonder if re could do an efficient job here

Answer (score 1):

Doing the job thoroughly is going to be hard.  The problem is recognizing when a function is defined; there can be many possible layouts, and it is hard to recognize all possibilities.  For example:

```
int x() { return 1; } int y(int z) { return z + 13; }
```

Most ad hoc systems won't detect `y`, even if they detect and handle `x`.  But that's lousy code layout, and you probably don't indulge in such code layouts.

How do you start your functions?

1. `static void function(int arg1) {`
2. `static void`
   `function(int arg1) {`
3. `static void`
   `function(int arg1)`
   `{`
4. `static void`
   `function(`
   `int arg1`
   `)`
   `{`
5. `static void`
   `function`
   `(`
   `int arg1`
   `)`
   `{`

Etc.  Depending on the notation(s) used, you need to write multiple different regular expressions.  Note that if you can't apply heuristics such as '`{` at start of line marks start of function - or structure/union definition, or data initialization' (because you use a `{` at the end of the line containing the function), it gets rather tricky.

You may need to tokenize the input, and keep track of whether you're inside a function definition.  Although my example used keywords, you can have functions using user-defined types only:

```
Xyz *pqr(Abc def)
{
```

Then, of course, you might have old code written without prototypes:

```
Xyz *pqr(def)
Abc def;
{
```

All this is before you get involved in preprocessor stuff, which can really confuse things:

```
#define BEGIN {
#define END }

Xyz *pqr(Abc def)
BEGIN
    ...
END
```

(The original Bourne shell source was, reputedly, written using macros akin to those.)

So, normally, you develop an ad hoc system for recognizing the functions laid out in the style used by your project.  One hopes that your project is systematic enough to have a limited variety of choices, but if this is old code that has been maintained over many years by many people, there are likely to be special cases all over the place.

Answer (score 0):

I have a simple solution, that is, mighty Macro! if you only want to apply these to a small set of functions, and they are not called by function pointer

here is the simple solution:

1 locate call functions' definitions and declearations

2 rename them to something else, for example: myfunc to _myfunc, only names changed in these functions so it's fairly easy to change back

3 define a macro, with the name myfunc of which do this: 1) print your log 2) call the original function

you can grab all these functions' declarations to a single macro definition file, do some simple text work(maybe with script lang help, or text editor macro help), but this solution is not good for vast amount of functions, and don't deal with function pointer.

for example, you have function like this:

```
int myfunc(int arg)
int myfunc(int arg){
    return 0;
}
```

rename myfunc to _myfunc and add a macro named myfunc

```
#define myfunc(arg)\
    print("print whatever you want!");\
    myfunc(arg);\
int _myfunc(int arg);
int _myfunc(int arg){
    return 0;
}
```

if macro not good enough, wrap it with another function

```
int myfunc(arg){
    print("print whatever you want!");
    return myfunc(arg);
}
int _myfunc(int arg);
int _myfunc(int arg){
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: HI, tdihp, i really want something automatic, otherwise, i could simply copy-paste this one line printf to each function myself.

Comment: @pepero maybe you are looking for some sort of c parser that parses c codes and give you a process interface. I did some google, maybe try something like pycparser? also check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2318347/library-to-parse-c-c-source-code

Answer (score 0):

If you want to debug linux kernel with printk and you want to get the call flow at run time, I have a very basic local solution for that.

Open your .c file in notepad++ --> ctrl+H --> Find what: \n{ -> Replace with: \n{ printk \("Your_Name: %s:%d \\n", __func__, __LINE__ \); --> Replace All

Comment kernel parent dir Makefile as like below:

+#KBUILD_CFLAGS += $(call cc-option,-Wdeclaration-after-statement,)

Hope it will solve your problem.

Comment: please visit and check [how to answer a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).